# Understanding the access of a variable assigned in initialize in Ruby

Tags: ruby, initialization, instance-variables, self

As a beginner, I've not quite got my head around `self` so I'm having trouble understanding how the `self.blogs` in initialize, and `blogs` then `self.blogs` on the next line after in the `add_blog` method, are all working together in the below code.

Why does `blogs` in the `add_blog` method access the same variable as `self.blogs` in initalize?
And then why is `self.blogs` used afterwards to sort the `blogs` array?

Also, would it matter if I used `@blogs` in initialize, instead of `self.blogs`?

```
class User
  attr_accessor :username, :blogs

  def initialize(username)
    self.username = username
    self.blogs    = []
  end

  def add_blog(date, text)
    added_blog = Blog.new(date, self, text)
    blogs << added_blog
    self.blogs = blogs.sort_by { |blog| blog.date }.reverse
    added_blog
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most method calls on self, `self.method_name` is equivalent to just `method_name`. That's not the case for methods whose name ends with an `=`, though.

The first thing to note, then, is that `self.blogs = etc` doesn't call a method named `blogs` and then somehow 'assign etc to it'; that line calls the method `blogs=`, and passes `etc` to it as an argument.

The reason you can't shorten that to just `blogs = etc`, like you can with other method calls, is because `blogs = etc` is indistinguishable from creating a new local variable named `blogs`.

When, on the previous line, you see a bare `blogs`, that is *also* a method call, and could just as easily have been written `self.blogs`. Writing it with an implicit receiver is just shorter. Of course, `blogs` is also potentially ambiguous as the use of a local variable, but in this case the parser can tell it's not, since there's no local variable named `blogs` assigned previously in the method (and if there had been, a bare `blogs` would have the value of that local variable, and `self.blogs` would be necessary if you had meant the method call).

As for using `@blogs =` instead of `self.blogs =`, in this case it would have the same effect, but there *is* a subtle difference: if you later redefine the `blogs=` method to have additional effects (say, writing a message to a log), the call to `self.blogs =` will pick up those changes, whereas the bare direct access will not. In the extreme case, if you redefine `blogs=` to store the value in a database rather than an instance variable, `@blogs =` won't even be *similar* anymore (though obviously that sort of major change in infrastructure will probably have knock-on effects internal to the class regardless).

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, we have to reveal the true nature of `attr_accessor`.

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar
end
```

is completely equivalent to

```
class Foo
  def bar
    @bar
  end

  def bar=(value)
    @bar = value
  end
end
```

You can see that `attr_accessor :bar` defines two instance methods `Foo#bar` and `Foo#bar=` that access an instance variable `@bar`.

Lets then look at your code.

`self.blogs = []` in `initialize` is actually calling the method `User#blogs=`, and through it sets the instance variable `@blogs` with an empty array. It can be written as `self.blogs=([])` but it's noisy, isn't it? By the way, you can't omit `self.` here otherwise it just sets a local variable.

`blogs << added_blog` calls the method `User#blog` which returns the value of `@blogs`. It can also be written as `self.blogs().push(added_blog)`, but again it's not rubyish. You can omit `self.` because there is no local variable named `blogs` in `User#add_blog`, so ruby **falls back** to call the instance method.

`self.blogs = blogs.sort_by { |blog| blog.date }.reverse` mixes call to `User#blogs=` and `User#blogs`.

Comment: Thank you so much! You're explanation has really helped me understand how it's all working.
There's just one thing I still don't quite get though - When you say 'you can't omit self. here otherwise it just sets a local variable.' - What would be/go wrong with setting a local variable in initialize? The code still seems to run OK if I use @ instead of self.

Comment: actually don't worry about my other question here; figured it out with the added help of the below answer too!

Answer (score 0):

`@variable` will directly access the instance variable for that class. Writing `self.variable` will send to the object a message `variable`. By default it will return the instance variable but it could do other things depending on how you set up your object. It could be a call to a method, or a subclass, or anything else.

The difference between calling `blogs` or `self.blogs` is totally up to syntax. If you use an opinionated syntax checker like rubocop it will tell you that you have a redundant use of `self`